# How do I automatically assign XML tags to blocks of text with R?

Tags: r, xml, corpus, data-wrangling

I have text that looks as follows:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I want to put every sentence in an XML tag `<sentence></sentence>` and every word inside a tag `<word></word>`. By sentence, I mean every string that ends with a period. By word, I mean every string followed by either a white space, a comma, or a period, like so (I have only tagged the words in the first sentence):

```xml
<sentence>
  <word>Lorem</word> <word>ipsum</word> <word>dolor</word>   
  <word>sit</word> <word>amet</word>, <word>consectetur</word> 
  <word>adipiscing <word>elit</word>, <word>sed</word>   
  <word>do</word> <word>eiusmod</word> <word>tempor</word> 
  <word>incididunt</word> <word>ut</word> <word>labore</word> 
  <word>et</word> <word>dolore</word> <word>magna</word> <word>aliqua</word>.</sentence> 
</sentence>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco   
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</sentence>
<sentence>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</sentence>
<sentence> 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</sentence>
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: How exactly are you defining a sentence? Are you just assuming that a period indicates a new sentence? Are are you trying to do some sort of natural language processing?

Comment: I believe that the ICU library has word-breaking rules for a wide variety of natural languages, but I don't know whether that's accessible from R.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.